# Change Screen Orientation but not to lock

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I want to change my device screen orientation programmaticaly. For this I can use:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

But this would lock my screen for entire activity lifecycle. I just want to change the screen orientation so that I can receive `onConfigurationChanged`callbacks.

This is how my manifest looks like for an Activity:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

So, my question here is if there's a way to change screen orientation for once and clear the flags from `setRequestedOrientation`

Comment: Do it programmatically, Have a base activity and default make the boolean true, so that all the activity will fall into one category, when ever you required change the value in child activity

Comment: Changing orientation is something that happens in response to the user. It makes no sense to do it programmatically. `setRequestedOrientation()` can be used in the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` to set the orientation just like declaring the orientation of the `Activity` in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **onResume()** .

I think this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Want to create a view on Run time. In onResume() create the view.